# Error with zipfile when installing tensorflow using wheel

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-wheel

Error : ERROR: Exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 189, in _main status = self.run(options, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper return func(self, options, args) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 400, in run pycompile=options.compile, File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/init.py", line 88, in install_given_reqs pycompile=pycompile, File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 796, in install requested=self.user_supplied, File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 827, in install_wheel requested=requested, File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 662, in _install_wheel file.save() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/install/wheel.py", line 427, in save with self._zip_file.open(zipinfo) as f: File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1510, in open raise BadZipFile("Bad magic number for file header") zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad magic number for file header

Downloaded Python wheel tensorflow-2.4.1-cp36-cp36-linux_aarch64.whl from https://github.com/Qengineering/TensorFlow-Raspberry-Pi_64-bit

Comment: did you follow all instructions on their [website](https://qengineering.eu/install-tensorflow-2.4.0-on-raspberry-64-os.html)?

Comment: I think the file is simply broken. Re-download it.

Comment: i just redownloaded the file and it works now. Thanks a lot